# Lowering webcam's microphone volume disables input audio

Tags: sound, webcam, microphone

I have Fantech Luminous C30 Webcam and Ubuntu 22.04. The webcam mic input works when volume is set at 100%. But when I lower the input volume from either settings or pavucontrol to even 99%, the webcam mic input totally stops as if webcam mic is muted (even though it is not). However, increasing input volume above 100% doesn't have any issue.